# Using an in-app purchase pauses my game

Tags: ios, background, in-app-purchase, nsnotificationcenter, foreground

I'm trying to implement in-app purchases to my game, but my app keeps pausing after I buy the premium content.  After a bit of trial and error, I found that my problem was in the view controller, where I had added two functions to pause and resume if the player exited my app.  It would seem that purchasing the product causes the app to enter the background, but finishing the purchase did not count as entering the foreground.  Is there any way around this?

```
-(void)appWillEnterBackground{
SKView* skview = (SKView*)self.view;
skview.paused = YES;
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appWillEnterForeground) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:NULL];
}

-(void)appWillEnterForeground{

SKView* skview = (SKView*)self.view;
skview.paused = NO;
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appWillEnterBackground) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:NULL];

}
```

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint in appWillEnterForeGround to make sure of this?

Comment: yes.  it went through appWillEnterBackground when the purchase started, but didn't go through appWillEnterForeground after the purchase

Comment: Have you tried - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
?

Comment: just tried it.  it still stayed paused

Comment: also just got a low battery warning and it also got stuck being paused